# Struts 2 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [validateLogin] associated with context path [/LoginApplication]

Tags: struts2, struts2-namespace, action-mapping

I tried out all the possible solution available on the internet.

**error :**

```
HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [validateLogin] associated with context path [/LoginApplication].
```

**struts.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="hello" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="validateLogin" 
            class="com.example.login.ValidationAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/result.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<form action="validateLogin">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="username">Username</label></td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="password">Password</label></td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: What version of S2 are you using? Did you try "/validateLogin.action"? Any reason you're not using the S2 tags? Also, you should probably put your JSP pages under WEB-INF to prevent direct client access. No need to specify the "execute" method since it's the default.

Comment: Put your project in development mode and post the logs we analyze the problem. http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/devmode.html

Comment: I am using struts-2.3.4.1. I am new to struts.

Comment: I have used the developer mode... m not getting any logs

Comment: how to access the jsp pages from the web-inf folder?

Comment: @piresashwin <result name="success">/WEB-INF/result.jsp</result>. BTW you do not need to write `name="success"` because it is also a default.

Comment: You are using very old DTD for struts.xml, please use the latest one `<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was a little weird.

i just removed `<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />` from the struts.xml file

and the program started working properly... and then i placed the same code back again in the struts.xml file and it was still running....

Comment: No, it's not the root cause at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `struts.xml` is in the right directory.
If you are using Eclipse, you can follow these steps :

1- Right-click on the project ⇾ properties ⇾ Deployment Assembly.

2- Make the deploy Path of your sources like this: [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UmAe.png)

> -/Src/main/java : WEB-INF/classes.
>
> -Struts2(library) : WEB-INF/lib.

3- Put the `struts.xml` in the directory which have a deploy Path withe `WEB-INF/classes`.
For example here you should put it in `/src/main/java`.[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiaPs.png)

Answer (score -1):

This error comes mostly when the package structure is not made correctly.

If the `web.xml` file and `struts.xml` file is created under correct package then both the XML files will be reflected automatically under Configuration files folder structure in Netbeans.

Please refer the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20rjV.png):